# Php includes and html tags

Tags: php, html

I have a website that I am building and I am planning to use php inlude for the header and footer.

Lets say the header is `<html>.....</html`

Footer is `<html>......</html>`

What happens with the beginning and ending of html tags on the same page?

Is there gonna be a problem?

Can there be two open and end tags on the same page?

```
header
```

```
footer
```

Comment: You really should strive for valid HTML. Also, there's no need to have those tags on your header and footer so I am unsure why you even have them there in the first place.

Comment: So John I should code: <html>php include (header)..... body.....php include(footer) </html>?

Comment: Yes. Your PHP includes should only generate the HTML you need to replace the PHP block with. For example, in `<html><head><% include(header.php); %></head><body>Hello</body></html>`, your `header.php` file would only need to output something like `echo "<title>Hello!</title>";`. It's been an awful long time since I did PHP so the syntax might not be right, but the idea is there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use "include", "require" or "require_once" on your page... the *included file* should contain **ONLY** valid markup. Think of your *include files* as what you would normally write between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

**EXAMPLE:**

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php require'includes/header.php' ?>

my body content goes here

<?php require'includes/footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<div id="header">
<div><img src="/where/my/image/is/filename.jpg" alt="my header image" title="my image title" /></div>
<div id="menu">this is where I will put my menu</div>
</div>
```

footer.php

```
<div id="footer">this is where I will put my footer content</div>
```

Notice that in the header.php and footer.php files the following lines have been removed...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Multiple `<head>`, `<html>`, `<body>` tags are generally ignored by modern "smart" browsers. They will just "rewrite your code for you" based on what the browser "thinks" you meant to write. **BUT** will it be correct!?

Do not rely on browsers to "fix" your mistakes. Write good, clean, valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Your include `header` should start with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
some meta tags, css and js
</head>
```

And you `footer` should end with

```
</html>
```

---

Here's an example of a small `html` page structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Example Explanation:

```
The `DOCTYPE` declaration defines the document type to be HTML
The text between `<html>` and `</html>` describes an HTML document
The text between `<head>` and `</head>` provides information about the document
The text between `<title>` and `</title>` provides a title for the document
The text between `<body>` and `</body>` describes the visible page content
The text between `<h1>` and `</h1>` describes a heading
The text between `<p>` and `</p>` describes a paragraph
```

---

**UPDATE**

> My questions is about having multiple opening and ending 
>    tags on a page because of php include

An `HTML` document can only have **ONE** `html` tag. If you just put several `HTML` together, it will be an invalid document, and the browsers **may** have problems displaying it.

Comment: Hi Pedro, I know about those descriptions. My questions is about having multiple opening and ending <html> </html> tags on a page because of php include.